# Installing Ubuntu in dual boot

Tags: dual-boot, grub2

I have installed ubuntu in dual boot with windows 10 but windows not booting, however that menu grub showing.
Help me please.

Comment: and does grub give an entry for booting windows?

Comment: UEFI or BIOS, normally pre-installed Windows is UEFI. And then you need to have Ubuntu in UEFI boot mode. And did you turn Windows fast start up off? Or have UEFI secure boot on. Grub has issues with both of those.

Comment: Can you explain me more , what should i do and thanks

Comment: @ravery yes grub give an entry for booting windows but i can't booting it